# Finding index of repeated word in file

Tags: python, file, directory

I am trying to write a function to find the index position of strings in a file.
In order to do this, I want to iterate with a loop over each line in the file.
Right now the file is called words.txt, consisting of:

```
hello
hi
hello
hi
hi
```

If I put 'hi' as an argument I want my code to print 1, 3, 4

As of now, here is my code:

```
def line(word, filename):
    f=open (filename, 'r')
    for (i , line) in enumerate (f):
        if word in line:
            return  i
```

As of now my code works but only prints out 1 instead of multiple values.
I am guessing this has to do with my enumerate function.
Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

When you `return` a value, your function exits immediately. A `print` statement does not have this effect. (If you really do want to return multiple values, you can try appending them to a list, and returning the list after iterating through every line.)

Answer (score 1):

Version with List comprehension:

```
def line(word, filename):
    f = dict(list(enumerate(open(filename,'r'))))
    return [k for k in f if word in f[k]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def line(word, filename):
    f = dict(list(enumerate(open(filename,'r'))))
    for k in f:
        if word in f[k]:
            print (k)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find exact word (not a part of the word inside another word), you should split the line on separate words using white-space sign ' ' and compare words. To check the occurrence of a word in a string:

```
import os

def list_of_indexes(word, filename):
    """ Return list of indexes with encounter of word in the line number """
    lst = []
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):  # file doesn't exist
        print('File does not exist')
        return lst  # return empty list
    f = open(filename, 'r')  # open file for reading
    for (i, line) in enumerate(f):
        if word in line:
            lst.append(i)
    f.close()  # close file before exit
    return lst

print(list_of_indexes('hi', 'filename.txt'))
```

For the 'filename.txt':

```
hello
hi
hello
hi
hi
how are you
fine
Hitchhaker
thanks
anchithere
ship
```

it will return:

```
D:\>python list_of_indexes.py
[1, 3, 4, 9, 10]
```